# Property is null in method 2 after being set in method 1

Tags: php, methods

hoping you can help me out with this question!

**Index.php**

```
include_once 'files.class.php';
$file_object = new FileObject('resources');
$file_object->ReturnCurrentDirectoryList();
```

**files.class.php**

```
class FileObject{
public $directory_list;

    function __construct($current_directory_in){
        $this->directory_list = $this->BuildCurrentDirectoryList($current_directory_in);
    }

    function BuildCurrentDirectoryList($current_directory_in){
        $i = 0;
        $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($current_directory_in);

        foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo){
            if ($fileinfo->isDir()){
                $this->directory_list[$i]['pathname'] = $fileinfo->getPathname();
            }elseif($fileinfo->isFile()){
                $this->directory_list[$i]['filename'] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }

    function ReturnCurrentDirectoryList(){
        var_dump($this->directory_list);
    }
}
```

At the end of all this, what is returned is

```
null
```

but what **should** be returned is

```
array  0 =>  array 'pathname' => string 'resources\.',  1 => array 'pathname' => string 'resources\..', 2 =>  array 'pathname' => string 'resources\Images'
```

I'm somewhat new to classes/methods..

Comment: Just spit out some debugging prints / vardumps to find out where it goes wrong

Comment: I've been using var_dump to check it out, but everything looks fine at the end of `BuildCurrentDirectoryList()` and then spits out a `null` in `ReturnCurrentDirectoryList()`. No clue why or what I can do to remove it.

Comment: You overwrite your `$this->directory_list` property (in the construct()) with the return of the function `BuildCurrentDirectoryList` which doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$this->directory_list = $this->BuildCurrentDirectoryList($current_directory_in);
```

You assign to `$this->directory_list` but `BuildCurrentDirectoryList` does not return anything. The function have side-effects only, no return value.

Remove the assignment so the constructor looks like this and you should be good to go:

```
$this->directory_list = array(); //I like to initialise arrays to the empty array
$this->BuildCurrentDirectoryList($current_directory_in);
```

Comment: Perfect! I feel so dumb after seeing that. Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe such things would be easier to spot if you wrote function specifications at the top of each function, with return value and side-effects?

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you are assigning directory_list to the return of BuildCurrentDirectoryList, but you are not returning nothing in BuildCurrentDirectoryList, you are assigning directory_list directly in that method. At the end, BuildCurrentDirectoryList returns NULL. So, either return the directory_list, or else just don't assign it like this:

```
function __construct($current_directory_in){
    $this->BuildCurrentDirectoryList($current_directory_in);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I feel so dumb after seeing that. Thank you :)